# specify allowed value range for boost::program_options value

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I want to set limits on value specified in command line. And it would be great if this range will be automatically printed within description like default value.

Also is is interesting if there is a way to create my own type and do specialization of `po::value` for my enum type.

For example

```
enum percent
{
   percent0,
   percent10,
   percent20,
   percent30,
   percent40,
   ...
   percent100
};

po::value<percent>() <-- gives compile time error
```

**update**

I would like to add information about allowed values to the `value_semantic` object, like it is done for the default value or for required flag.

I noticed that `typed_value` class is polymorphic and can be extended, so I want to create a new class

```
class range_int : public po::typed_value<int> {}
```

and later when iterating description options I can do `dynamic_cast<>` and check if value is range_int, but I don't like this solution because of cast is required for it, but there is no way to add virtual functions to the base interface.

The purpose of this is to extend program options. I need to write another description output function which will output program options in format that is easy to parse (for example XML). I also need to add range to some of the values, so I need this information be stored in program options.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [custom validator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp123425568) with a custom type to hold your information.
The example provided is self explanatory

Comment: @axe Since this answered you query, please accept the answer.